# Compare two columns of Unequal Length in R using logical Operator

Tags: time-series, date-comparison

I am dealing with a big time series dataset, And I would like to compare two columns
So my first Column looks like

```
            timeperiod          timefortreatment
       2014-08-01 00:00:00        102.81818
       2014-08-01 01:00:00         12.34483
       2014-08-01 02:00:00         35.67568
       2014-08-01 03:00:00        125.57692
       2014-08-01 04:00:00         97.56250
       2014-08-01 05:00:00         36.66667
```

And the second column looks like

```
        arrivaltime         
       2014-08-01 00:14:00       
       2014-08-01 00:22:00         
       2014-08-01 00:47:00         
       2014-08-01 01:07:00        
       2014-08-01 01:19:00         
       2014-08-01 01:53:00
```

Both are of unequal lengths with second being larger than first. I have to compare the first column with second to get a final one which looks like below. The logic for comparison is that if arrival time  in the second column is less than the entry in first column (time  being 1 hour here) it gets the value of time of treatment for that specific  period

```
             arrival          timefortreatment
       2014-08-01 00:14:00        102.81818
       2014-08-01 00:22:00        102.81818
       2014-08-01 00:47:00        102.81818
       2014-08-01 01:07:00         12.34483
       2014-08-01 01:19:00         12.34483
       2014-08-01 01:53:00         12.34483
```

I have made a logic based on two `for` loops and it is taking forever for 50k + values:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(date)) 
{
    for (j in 1:nrow(period))
    { 
        if (date[i,1]>=period[j,])
        { 
            z[i,]=t[j,] 
            j=j+1
        } 
    } 
    i=i+1 
}
```

I was wondering is there any other way in which this can be done. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Editing my answer to accommodate for the cases with different time  period.

```
             timeperiod                  timefortreatment
              2014-08-01 00:14:00               75
              2014-08-01 00:19:00              143
              2014-08-01 00:44:00              126
              2014-08-01 01:04:00              125
              2014-08-01 01:19:00              125
              2014-08-01 01:49:00              122
```

For this case, output will be as shown below based  on same  logic i.e. (arrival>=time period)

```
              arrival          timefortreatment
       2014-08-01 00:14:00            75
       2014-08-01 00:22:00           143
       2014-08-01 00:47:00           126
       2014-08-01 01:07:00           125
       2014-08-01 01:19:00           125
       2014-08-01 01:53:00           122
```

Let me know if more details needed

Comment: My Comaprison code like this for (i in 1:nrow(date))
{for (j in 1:nrow(period)){
  if (date[i,1]>=period[j,]){ 
    
    z[i,]=t[j,]
    j=j+1}
}
  i=i+1
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, with only one `for` loop, faster solution exists.

```
df1 = data.frame(timeperiod = seq(as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 05:00:00"), by = "1 hour"),
            timefortreatment = c(102.81818, 12.34483, 35.67568, 125.57692, 97.56250, 36.66667))
df2 = data.frame(arrivaltime = c(as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 00:14:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 00:22:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 00:47:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 01:07:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 01:19:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 01:53:00")))


library(stringr)
df2$time_min = as.POSIXct(paste0(str_sub(df2$arrivaltime, 1, 14), "00:00"))

for (i in 1:nrow(df2))
{
 df2$timefortreatment[i] = df1$timefortreatment[df1$timeperiod == df2$time_min[i]]
}
```

**EDIT**

With no periodicity in timeperiod, you can use `difftime` function :

```
df1 = data.frame(timeperiod = c(as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 00:14:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 00:19:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 00:44:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 01:04:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 01:19:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 01:49:00")), timefortreatment = c(75, 143, 126, 125, 125, 122))
df2 = data.frame(arrivaltime = c(as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 00:14:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 00:22:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 00:47:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 01:07:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 01:19:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-08-01 01:53:00")))

for (i in 1:nrow(df2))
{
  df2$timefortreatment[i] = df1$timefortreatment[which.min(abs(difftime(df2$arrivaltime[i], df1$timeperiod)))]
}


# APPLY solution 

my_function = function(value)
{
  output = df1$timefortreatment[which.min(abs(difftime(value, df1$timeperiod)))]
}
df2$timefortreatment = apply(df2, 1, my_function)


> df2
          arrivaltime timefortreatment
1 2014-08-01 00:14:00               75
2 2014-08-01 00:22:00              143
3 2014-08-01 00:47:00              126
4 2014-08-01 01:07:00              125
5 2014-08-01 01:19:00              125
6 2014-08-01 01:53:00              122
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, This solved one part of my problem, As timeperiod is not always of 1 hour and it keeps on changing I am looking for some generic way in achieving this

Comment: Let us know cases where timeperiod is not 1h to see if we can help you.

Comment: I have edited  my question to accommodate other scenarios too